# Getting "invalid entry size" when trying to import Excel xlsx file to R

Tags: r, xlsx

Every time I enter this line

```
cameradata <- read.xlsx("./data/cameras.xlsx" , 1)
```

I get error:

> Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod",
>   cl,  : java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 500
>   but got 502 bytes)

I have tried to clear RAM but file size is 10kp

Comment: If you're sure there is nothing corrupt with the Excel file (that is a possibility since `read.xlsx` is tossing an error on decompression), have you tried `gdata` or the [myriad of other ways](http://www.r-bloggers.com/read-excel-files-from-r/) to read an Excel (XLSX) file into R? Without posting a link to the Excel file, it's unlikely you'll get a concrete resolution/suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-
May be this can work. It worked for me

1)  when downloading the xlsx file, use this 
download.file(fileURL, destfile="./whatever", mode="wb")

2)  Switched to regular R, not R Studio,

Answer (score 0):

The xlsx file you are trying to read maybe damaged. Try redownload the file or read another "healthy" xlsx file.

Answer (score 0):

I had experience exactly the same issue.
What I did to resolve the problem was:

1. I had defined separate variable "fileURL2" and assigned "XLSX" download link
2. I had defined separate variable "cameraData2" and loaded XLSX file to it
3. I had downloaded file directly with Firefox and open it with MS Excel to assure it is OK, then I had save it to the working directory of "R" overwriting existing "cameras.xlsx" file
4. After new attempt to read the file with "R" read.xlsx() - was successful

In conclusion it seems that "R" had corrupted XLSX file during the download  - which might be caused by a BUG inside of current version of the language.